# Checking remaining gas

Tags: nearprotocol

There's 3 related questions here:

I can look at an account's NEAR balance before and after a near-api-js `account.functionCall` to determine how much gas the tx took, but is
there a better way to extrapolate that info from the metadata of the call?

Also, is there a cap for how much gas I can feed into a function call?

From within a functional call (in rust) is it possible to use env:: to see
how much gas is remaining in the course of operations?

I'm trying to set up the control flow so
that the function will quit working in time and never throw a 'ran out of gas' error, but only do as much work as it has gas to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I can look at an account's NEAR balance before and after a near-api-js account.functionCall to determine how much gas the tx took, but is there a better way to extrapolate that info from the metadata of the call?

Well, to compute the transaction fee you can query the transaction status ([`tx`](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/transactions#transaction-status)/[`EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status`](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/transactions#transaction-status-with-receipts) JSON RPC endpoints) and sum up the `tokens_burnt` from all the `receipt_outcomes` and `transaction_outcome`. If you want to profile the gas usage, you should sum up `gas_burnt` from all the `receipt_outcomes` and `transaction_outcome`.

> Also, is there a cap for how much gas I can feed into a function call?

Yes, on mainnet genesis it is [set to 1 PetaGas (1_000 TeraGas)](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/6a31f357e8c86c5783b8e502d80c9a5d68de2d59/nearcore/res/mainnet_genesis.json#L15).

> From within a functional call (in rust) is it possible to use env:: to see how much gas is remaining in the course of operations?

[`near_sdk::env::prepaid_gas()`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/3.1.0/near_sdk/env/fn.prepaid_gas.html) minus
[`near_sdk::env::gas_used()`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/3.1.0/near_sdk/env/fn.used_gas.html)